# Application Development: Cocoa vs Sencha vs Others

Tags: cocoa, xcode, ipad, extjs

I'm a developer most comfortable with web languages (PHP, Javascript etc.). Now, My company wants to start making iPad apps for pharma sales reps that basically gives a nice introduction to drugs.

We used to subcontract it but we want to bring it in house. It's a very big plus for me financially if I can take on the jobs and do them right. Now doing my research, these apps aren't crazy; they just kinda need to act like a powerpoint slideshow with a little animation and interaction.

**I don't know Cocoa.** I know there will also be a learning curve with it as well. I do know Sencha slightly. Does anyone here have any experience with either of these platforms and do you think it's a "might as well learn cocoa" type of thing? The only reason I like Sencha is becuase you program in Web languages and can port it to app stores. Any ideas? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is always just to learn Cocoa in situations like this, but Sencha is actually surprising not-bullshit. I'm really impressed with it.

However, I wanted to note a few things: I don't know exactly what you mean by "port it to app stores", but I want to be sure you don't delude yourself into thinking than an app written with Sencha would be usable on any platform other than iPad. Of course you could load a page written in Sencha on non-iPad device, but the entire point of Sencha is tailoring your web application to work surprisingly well on an iPad. So, it will be out of place anywhere else, and given the quality of current iPad competitors, it'd be unlikely to perform adequately off of the iPad at this time.

So, if you want to use Sencha, it has to be for the right reasons (of which there are two):

1. You want more flexibility in deployment: you don't want to have to deal with Apple's Enterprise deployment system. Apple's not interested in apps that only pertain to one company (internal software) on the App Store, so if you want to go the Cocoa route, you'll have to use their Enterprise Ad-Hoc deployment.
2. You don't want to / can't afford to take the time and learn Cocoa (really, to make an app that doesn't sucks will probably take at least a year of experience, trial and error, etc.; at least, that's how it was for me).

If either one of these things is true, I'd go the Sencha route. But as an advocate of iOS, I really hope you take the time and learn Cocoa! I believe I speak for all the Cocoa developers on Stack Overflow when I say that we'd be happy to help you with any questions you may have as you go. Good luck, whatever you decide!

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I appreciate it. I like sencha because it's going to be easier and quicker but I don't like because (just assumption) it's not as powerful and may not give you the "true" app feel.

Comment: Yeah. I'mma put this out there, though: of all the HTML 5 solutions, Sencha is the only one that even gets close to a "true" app feel, as you put it. Everything else is basically bullshit. (So, thanks for considering Sencha instead of something truly awful!)

Comment: +1 - A native app is indeed the ideal. But life isn't always ideal, and of the HTML 5 alternatives, Sencha seems to suck the least. :-)